# jQuery - cannot get value of dynamically added checkbox

Tags: jquery

Using php, I add checkboxes:

```
<div class="member"><input type="checkbox" name="team-members[]" value="5"></div>
```

And I can get the id when the checkbox is selected:

```
$('input[name="team-members[]"]').click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

I can add a checkbox to the array via ajax:

```
<div class="member"><input type="checkbox" name="team-members[]" value="9"></div>
```

But when I click the dynamically added checkbox - the alert does not fire.
There are no js errors in the console.
How do I get the id of the new checkbox when it is clicked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: BTW, your title makes little sense with your content, considering none of the elements have ids...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all dynamically added elements you need to use the `.on()` method and not `.click()`:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="team-members[]"]', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});


function addCheckBox() {
    let div = $('.member');
    let chkBx = document.createElement('input');
    chkBx.type = "checkbox";
    chkBx.name = "team-members[]";
    chkBx.value = "10";
  
    div.append(chkBx);
}

addCheckBox();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="member"><input type="checkbox" name="team-members[]" value="5"></div>
```

You can find a good explanation of why this is necessary [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099940/click-event-is-not-working-for-dynamically-added-button).